# Laptop temperature is too high with minimal usage

Tags: 16.04, drivers, dell, temperature

I have  Dell laptop model(inspiron 5110n) Core i7 processor with 2 graphic cards; one nvidea Gforce and another one by Intel
I installed ubuntu 16.4 and without opening many programs, its temperature becomes too high , it's really annoying and it didn't happen before with Windows.
What is the reason of this and how can i solve this problem.?